# Whats the role of these transistors

Tags: transistors, amplifier

[image: transistors]

I'm asked to explain what the function of transistors Q1-Q2 and Q3-Q13 are.

So far i've been unable to figure it out. If you know what the functions are, please also tell my how you derived it.

Comment: @phil-frost only 1/2 right, but perhaps we shouldn't be doing his homework for him?

Comment: phil-frost: yes. I can see how Q13+Q1 are differential amplifiers. Q2+Q3 I find trickier to see. But the question I actually asked is is the role of the transitor pairs Q1-Q2 and Q3-Q13. (why are they connected as in the picture)

Comment: @rawbrawb I agree that you shouldn't just tell me the solution. But can you give me some hints. Should I try to redraw it in some way, or something else?

Comment: how about popping into chat?

Comment: @tgoossens if you want to pop by chat I can take through how to analyze the circuit.  Long comment trails aren't recommended, chat is at the top of the page.

Comment: I think this is sad, because I'm not a EE student, and I want to know the answer as well, and unfortunately the answer isn't here (on a QA site). I'm not very active here on EE, but I think this meta of StackOverflow also apply here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?lq=1 `We're not discouraging students from asking questions on Stack Overflow! However, the consensus is that everyone can benefit from answers that explain why not just how, and everyone should be encouraged to ask questions that are clear and complete`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't just want to answer your homework problem for you, but I'll give you some things to think about.

For Q13,Q1, consider how the collector currents react to a common mode voltage change on Vinp and Vinn, and a differential mode voltage change.  If both Vinp and Vinn were let's say 5V above Vee (and Vcc well above that), then they were both raised by 1 V, what happens to the collector currents of Q13 and Q1?  Now what if Vinp were raised by 1/2 V and Vinn lowered by 1/2 V.  What happens to the collector currents then?

As for Q2 and Q3, look at how they work with Q11.  This is easier to see with one of Q2 or Q3 removed.  Look up something called a "current mirror" after you've thought about it for a while.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: What exactly do you think I said is wrong, misleading, etc?  I thought I gave the OP enough information to learn, but not enough so he doesn't have to learn what this homework is about.

Answer (score 1):

This sure looks like a home work problem ...

So no direct answers ...

Just to help, Q11, Q3 and Q2 all have their bases connected together - drawing the line *through* the transistor confuses some people.

Q11 is connected in a particular way, can you think of what a 2 terminal semi-conductor device might be?

And why is that base voltage be shared ?

Q1 and Q13 is perhaps the most iconic transistor configuration in transistor design.  The fact that you **don't** recognize it tells me you haven't spent any time on reading your text book.

Comment: -1 for being mean. Not everyone with a textbook is taking an electronics class, or has been guided through an electronics curriculum in the best order.

Comment: Like i said in the comments. I actually DO recognize the differential amplifier. I'm having difficulties interpreting the combined workings of the differential amplifier with Q2-Q3 (which i just realized that in combination with Q11 is in fact a current mirror).

Comment: OK, that is the first step.  So the 4 transistors Q1,2,3,13 make up One differential amplifier, Q2 and Q3 are the current loads that are mirrored off of Q11.  What role do the R's play?

Comment: @tgoossens just to correct my sentence above,  I shouldn't have said "... are the current loads ..."  but I should have said "... are current loads ..." that may lead you astray.

Answer (score 1):

Useful background reading terms : common base, cascode, folded cascode, Miller capacitance.

Another interesting question is why choose a PNP transistor for Q1?

Comment: I _think_ that he's just concerned about the front end Q1,2,3,13 so cascoding doesn't come into the picture yet.  I may be wrong.

Comment: take another look at Q1 and Q2 :-)